# Calculating precision, recall and F1 score per class in a multilabel classification problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, precision-recall

I'm trying to calculate the precision, the recall and the F1-Score per class in my multilabel classification problem. However, I think I'm doing something wrong, because I am getting really high values, and the F1 Score for the whole problem is 0.66. However, I'm getting +0.8 f1-score in the individual classes.

This is how I am doing it right now:

```
confusion_matrix = multilabel_confusion_matrix(gold_labels, predictions)

assert(len(confusion_matrix) == 6)

for label in range(len(labels_reduced)):

    tp = confusion_matrix[label][0][0]
    fp = confusion_matrix[label][0][1]
    fn = confusion_matrix[label][1][0]
    tn = confusion_matrix[label][1][1]

    precision = tp+fp
    precision = tp/precision

    recall = tp+fn
    recall = tp/recall

    f1_score_up = precision * recall
    f1_score_down = precision + recall
    f1_score = f1_score_up/f1_score_down
    f1_score = 2 * f1_score

    print(f"Metrics for {labels_reduced[label]}.")
    print(f"Precision: {precision}")
    print(f"Recall: {recall}")
    print(f"F1-Score: {f1_score}")
```

Are these results okay? Do they make sense? Am I doing something wrong? How would you calculate those metrics? I'm using huggingface transformers for loading the models and getting the predictions, and sklearn for calculating the metrics.

Comment: Since you are already using sklearn, is there any specific reason to avoid the in-built [F1 score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`classification_report`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) function from `sklearn`:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

labels = [[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
predictions = [[[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]

report = classification_report(labels, predictions)
print(report)
```

Which outputs:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00         2
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
           2       1.00      1.00      1.00         2

   micro avg       0.80      0.80      0.80         5
   macro avg       0.67      0.67      0.67         5
weighted avg       0.80      0.80      0.80         5
 samples avg       0.89      0.83      0.82         5
```